PHP - Form doesn't submit $_POST on a Div text
I cannot get this "about_me_container" div in this form to submit the $_POST. I understand divs aren't meant to be used with $_POST so I changed the div into input type="text" and textarea but it still will not work. I also tried to add the text from "about_me_container" to add to the "hidden_about_me" through Javascript. What am I doing wrong? Or can you just point me in the right direction? Thank you
mypage.php
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        if (isset($_POST['about_me_container']) && $_SESSION['logged_in'] == true) {
            $username = $_SESSION['username'];
            
            echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['about_me_container']);
            
        }
        else if (isset($_POST['hidden_about_me']) && $_SESSION['logged_in'] == true) {
            $username = $_SESSION['username'];
            
            echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['hidden_about_me']);
            
        }
    }

?>

<form id="about_me_text" action="mypage.php" method="post">
    <div id="about_me_title_row"> 
        <label for="about_me_label"><h3>About Me</h3></label> 
        <input type="submit" class="mypage_button" id="edit_about_me" value="Edit">
        <input type="submit" class="mypage_button" id="okay_about_me" value="Ok">
    </div>

    <div class="about_me_flex">
    <div id="about_me_containment">

    <div id="about_me_container" contenteditable="false"></div>

    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_about_me" id="hidden_about_me" value=""/>

    </div>
</form>

mypage.js
window.onload = function() {

    let editAboutMe = document.querySelector("#edit_about_me");
    let okayAboutMe = document.querySelector("#okay_about_me");

    let aboutMeContainer = document.querySelector("#about_me_container");
    let hiddenAboutMe = document.querySelector("#hidden_about_me");

    editAboutMe.addEventListener("click", editAboutMeText);
    okayAboutMe.addEventListener("click", okayAboutMeText);

    function editAboutMeText(e) {
        aboutMeContainer.contentEditable = "true";
        //aboutMeContainer.removeAttribute("readonly");
        aboutMeContainer.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    function okayAboutMeText(e) {
        aboutMeContainer.contentEditable = "false";
        //aboutMeContainer.setAttribute("readonly", "");
        aboutMeContainer.style.backgroundColor = "lightcyan";
        moveHiddenText(e);
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    
    function moveHiddenText(e) {
        hiddenAboutMe.value = aboutMeContainer.innerText;
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}



Your submit buttons never actually submit the page, to be processed by PHP, because you use e.preventDefault(); to stop the submit.

Thanks, removing e.preventDefault() fixed it. Thanks.

Your form submission issue likely stems from the "Edit" and "Ok" buttons triggering form submission before the JavaScript can update the hidden input. To fix this, update the hidden input field in the moveHiddenText function and only then allow the form to submit.
Change the type of the "Ok" button to button to prevent it from submitting the form prematurely:
<input type="button" class="mypage_button" id="okay_about_me" value="Ok">

Modify the JavaScript to submit the form manually after updating the hidden input:
window.onload = function() {
    let editAboutMe = document.querySelector("#edit_about_me");
    let okayAboutMe = document.querySelector("#okay_about_me");

    let aboutMeContainer = document.querySelector("#about_me_container");
    let hiddenAboutMe = document.querySelector("#hidden_about_me");

    editAboutMe.addEventListener("click", editAboutMeText);
    okayAboutMe.addEventListener("click", okayAboutMeText);

    function editAboutMeText(e) {
        aboutMeContainer.contentEditable = "true";
        aboutMeContainer.style.backgroundColor = "white";
        e.preventDefault();
    }

    function okayAboutMeText(e) {
        aboutMeContainer.contentEditable = "false";
        aboutMeContainer.style.backgroundColor = "lightcyan";
        moveHiddenText();
        document.querySelector("#about_me_text").submit();
    }
    
    function moveHiddenText() {
        hiddenAboutMe.value = aboutMeContainer.innerText;
    }
}


There are many ways to solve this puzzle, and I agree that yours would work, but you're incorrect when you assume that: "the "Edit" and "Ok" buttons triggering form submission before the JavaScript can update the hidden input". Click events on submit buttons are processed before form submission. Form submission is always last. See; Understanding JavaScript onClick and onSubmit Events and the Order of Execution.
